# Why when counter is equal to three does it not redirect the page?

Tags: php, counter

lately I have run into an issue when setting up a quiz in PHP. I have a quiz set up using a counter that is then used to check the answer, for instance if the question is correct the counter goes up by one to move onto next question. At the end of the quiz I wanted a way to say that once all questions are answered to redirect the page. In order to achieve this I thought the easiest way would be to set another `else{ if{}}` statement that says when `$currentQuestion==3` to redirect the page. Once the counter hits three however it is not redirecting the page. Here is the example:

```
$currentQuestion = 0;
if(isset($_POST["currentQuestion"])){
$currentQuestion = $_POST["currentQuestion"];
if($_POST["guess"] == $questionsAndAnwsers[$currentQuestion] ["answer"]){
     $currentQuestion++;
     print("Answer Correct<br>");
     print("Next Question Below<br><br>");
   } 
   else {
   $currentQuestion=0;
     print("You have failed..");
   }}
   else{
  if($currentQuestion==3){
  header("Location:   http://students.purchase.edu/martin.mcnicholas/scriptingfortheweb/index2. html"); /* Redirect browser */
exit();
  }
  }
```

At fist I thought ok maybe it didn't recognize the number of the counter however as seen above with:

```
else {
$currentQuestion=0;
 print("You have failed..");
 }}
```

I did manage to set it to zero to return to original first question. I also was able to change it to any counter number and when answered incorrectly I would be dropped off at the question corresponding to the counter. I also attempted placing the else if within the `if(isset($_POST["currentQuestion"])){` however that just breaks my program completely.

Part of coding containing html:

```
// current question
$currentQuestion = 0;
if(isset($_POST["currentQuestion"])){
 $currentQuestion = $_POST["currentQuestion"];
 if($_POST["guess"] == $questionsAndAnwsers[$currentQuestion]["answer"]){
     $currentQuestion++;
     print("Answer Correct<br>");
     print("Next Question Below<br><br>");
   } 
   else {
   $currentQuestion=0;
     print("You have failed..");
   }}
   else{
  if($currentQuestion==3){
  header("Location: http://students.purchase.edu/martin.mcnicholas/scriptingfortheweb/index2.html"); /* Redirect browser */
exit();
 }
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="">
<label for="question"><?php echo ($currentQuestion+1).". ".   $questionsAndAnwsers[$currentQuestion]["question"];?></label>
<input type="hidden" name="currentQuestion" value="<?php echo $currentQuestion;?>">
<input type="text" name="guess" value="" placeholder="Answer...">
<input type="submit" value="Next Question">
</form>
```

Comment: We assume you have an `<input name="currentQuestion">` in the form  -can you post the relevant part of the HTML form that submits the next question and tracks the state of the last one? I would note that `$_SESSION` is probably more appropriate to use here to track question state on the server side than relying on the form sent back.

Comment: header should be place in a function before any html code. Put it in a func therefore

Comment: Use proper formatting and indentation of the code. If you did, you'd see that the `if($currentQuestion == 3) {` would only be checked if `$_POST["currentQuestion"]` is not set, so `$currentQuestion` would be set to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the proper order to check the conditions.

```
$currentQuestion = 0;
if(isset($_POST["currentQuestion"])){
    $currentQuestion = $_POST["currentQuestion"];
    if($currentQuestion==3){
        header("Location:   http://students.purchase.edu/martin.mcnicholas/scriptingfortheweb/index2. html"); /* Redirect browser */
        exit();
    }else if($_POST["guess"] == $questionsAndAnwsers[$currentQuestion] ["answer"]){
        $currentQuestion++;
        print("Answer Correct<br>");
        print("Next Question Below<br><br>");
    }else{
        $currentQuestion=0;
        print("You have failed..");
    }
}
```

First I get the currentQuestion value.
If it is = 3 then I exit;
If it is not I check if it is the right answer;
If it is not I exit again

Please note that indentation of your code is not just aesthetic but will save you a lot of headache

Comment: thank you so much with your code and Thomas' explanation I understand the purpose of having the header before the execution of the checking code. And the indentations are my fault when indenting on here to place the code in I did not keep the proper indentations

Answer (score 0):

This is not an asnwer. The right answer has been given by Lelio.

This describes brievely the mindset to solve that kind of issue.

---

Let's analyse your code...

First you init `$currentQuestion`, and set it to 0

```
$currentQuestion = 0;
```

Then you check if the POST variable `currentQuestion` is set

```
if(isset($_POST["currentQuestion"])){
```

Else (thus, if and only if the POST variable `currentQuestion` is NOT set)...

```
}else{
```

...you do the following

```
    if($currentQuestion==3){
        header("Location:   http://students.purchase.edu/martin.mcnicholas/scriptingfortheweb/index2. html"); /* Redirect browser */
        exit();
    }
```

Right?

So now, consider that your POST variable = 3 (ie, is SET to 3), and read the above again.

How do you expect that it will arrive to :

```
    if($currentQuestion==3){
```

?

Comment: Ah thank you so much for the explanation like this though it is so much clearer and easier to understand where I needed to get from to.